# Alternate between URLs for each onclick of href

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion

All -

The functionality I am trying to implement is as follows

I have a link on the page. For each click on the link, the href attribute has to change. For example, the link would start with a href value

```
<a href="www.google.com">Click Me</a>
```

For second click, it should change to www.yahoo.com, and third click, back to www.google.com, and so on. For just one user, I wrote the following code in jquery

```
 $(".clickMe").bind("click", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var currURL = $(this).attr("href");
  console.log($(this));
  if(currURL === 'www.google.com') {
    $(this).attr("href","www.yahoo.com");
    currURL = "www.yahoo.com";
  } else {
    $(this).attr("href","www.google.com");
    currURL = "www.google.com";
  }

  window.location = currURL;
});
```

How can I alternate the URLs between multiple users? If first users clicks the link, the href should point to www.google.com, and for second user, it should point to www.yahoo.com etc.

Comment: easiest would be to store the url in a database and update the link with ajax on the fly. better would be to use websockets.

Comment: You can't do it client-side, because the browser is agnostic to other clients. The way to tie clients together is by using a DB to store the current URL

Comment: Sorry, but I have to ask....why would you want to do this? Why should the URL I be sent to depend on what another user clicked on? This sounds like a user experience nightmare. Going to different URLS when I would click is bad enough, but to want to change the URL I go to because someone else clicked the same link is...baffling.

Comment: @ScottStroz: The actual link will go to two different forms, and metrics would be collected on which form would the user fill out completely or which form the users mostly abandon in middle.

Comment: Sounds like A/B testing. Try randomizing the URLs instead of persisting the previous click.

Comment: Ok, can this be done with Javascript so that both the URLs have equal chance?

Comment: That makes sense..thanx. However, I think the best way to handle this is on the server side...not the client side. Have ALL links go to the same URL and then redirect the request based on where the previous request was sent. You can store where previous request was sent by using the `application` scope (but make sure you use locking). Trying to sync the URL across multiple clients would prove complex. Sending them all to same URL is quick and easy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best way for you to handle this would be on the server side, not the client side.

You could do the following:

Have all links go to the same URL/page

Param and application variable that determines where the first user should be sent -

```
<cflock timeout = "60" scope = "application" type = "Exclusive">
<cfparam name="application.url" default="http://google.com" />
</cflock>
```

Use logic that grabs that URL and then changes it to new URL for next request -

```
<cfset myURl = application.url /> 
<cflock timeout = "60" scope = "application" type = "Exclusive">
<cfif myUrl EQ 'http://google./com'>
  <cfset application.url = 'http://yahoo.com' />
<cfelse>
  <cfset application.url = 'http://google.com' />
</cflock>
```

Finally, use `cflocation` to redirect user

```
<cflocation url="#myurl#" addToekn="false" />
```

If you are using ColdFusion 9 or higher, you can use a ternaty operator instead of the `if/else`.

```
<cfset application.url = myUrl EQ 'http://google./com' ? 'http://yahoo.com' : 'http://google./com' />
```

Comment: Thanks Scott. But how to handle this on a static html page. This is the reason I was looking for JavaScript solution. Is it not possible with Javascript or is it not recommended?

Comment: Why did you tag the question as 'ColdFusion' if you were not looking for a ColdFusion answer? Can it be done on the client side? Yes. Will it be easy? No. Here is the problem. Let's say you have 10 users visit the page at the same time. You need to capture each time one of them clicks the link, and then broadcast that info to each of the remaining clients. You could use websockets....but, it is not easy to do, especially if you do not a server side solution.

Comment: Thank you. I tagged it Coldfusion as an alternative if it is not possible with Client side. We use Coldfusion CMS, and generate HTML pages

Comment: Even if your CMS generates .html pages, you can still have the links point to a ColdFusion page to determine which form they should fill out...even if those forms are .html pages themselves

Answer (score 2):

There's no way of doing it with client-side javascript only. You must use either Ajax queries to a server or websockets.

Here's a very light sample (This is certainly not the best one, but I keep it simple to make it easy to understand)

Client-side (JS with complete Fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/DxNxj/1) :

```
function manageURL(updateServer){
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'index.php'
    data: {
        action: (updateServer) ? 'setNextURL' : 'getNextURL'
    }, 
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        $("#url").html(data);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("Can't retrieve URL");
    }
  });
}
```

Server-side (PHP) :

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['action']){
    if($_GET['action'] == 'getNextURL'){
        echo getURL();
    else if($_GET['action'] == 'setNextURL'){
        echo getURL(true);
    }
}

function getURL($next = false){
    $url = file_get_contents('url.txt');
    if($next){
        switch($url){
            case "http://google.fr":
                $url = "http://yahoo.com";
                break;
            case "http://yahoo.com":
                $url = "http://google.fr";
                break;
        }
        file_put_contents('url.txt', $url);
    }
    return $url;
}

?>
```

Comment: this isn't an answer. OP didn't say they *only* want to use client-side javascript. there are many ways to solve this problem.

Comment: I'd like to add it as a comment, but I can't because of my low rep. I agree I should have added some AJAX samples like below. Apologies

Comment: Well, you got me :) Done.

Comment: Question was tagged with ColdFusion, why would you provide a PHP solution?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in Javascript as JS runs in the users browser and has no link whatsoever to another user's browser. An option could be to not directly link to an url, but redirect the user to a 'chooser-script' (php or whatever). Then do something like this (php example):

```
$x = 'google.com';
$y = 'google.com';
$last_url = ''; // get it from a database or file or whatever
if($last_url == $x) {
    $redirect_url = $y;
} else {
    $redirect_url = $x;
}
update_last_url($redirect_url);
header('Location: '. $redirect_url;
```

Answer (score 1):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/uvzTc/)

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.clickToggle = function(func1, func2) {
        var funcs = [func1, func2];
        this.data('toggleclicked', 0);
        this.click(function() {
            var data = $(this).data();
            var tc = data.toggleclicked;
            $.proxy(funcs[tc], this)();
            data.toggleclicked = (tc + 1) % 2;
        });
        return this;
    };
}(jQuery));
$('#click_me').clickToggle(function(){
    $(this).attr("href","http://www.google.com");
},function(){
    $(this).attr("href","http://www.yahoo.com");
});
```

It can be done through ajax only,we will have to keep on check over every user if the user clicks link update the link for every user.

Comment: how does this handle multiple users?

Comment: it can be done through ajax only,we will have to keep on check over every user if the user clicks link update the link for every user

Comment: This will not update the URL for other users viewing the initial page when one user clicks the link.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that how are you identifying the second user.

Anyhow I am using toggle function of jquery.

please find the updated script with example [Here](http://jsbin.com/aqipuv/2/edit)

Thanks